# Elasticsearch - Install stored scripts into filesystems

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I hace a EL 7.6.1 cluster with 4 nodes.

I want install some stored scripts.
Into documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html and) I only read about send a POST with somethint like this...

```
POST _scripts/calculate-score
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "Math.log(_score * 2) + params.my_modifier"
  }
}
```

But I want install those scripts droping them into the filesystem.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400142/elasticsearch-how-to-store-scripts-in-config-scripts-directory) too but doesn't work.

If I copy those script into scripts folder, nothing happeds (neither in logs or GET _cluster/state/metadata?pretty&filter_path=**.stored_scripts).

My scripts looks like this... build_user_sessions_init_script.painless

These permisions

```
root@thorin:/# ls -la scripts/build_user_sessions_init_script.painless
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 119 Mar 20 08:56 scripts/build_user_sessions_init_script.painless
```

With this code.

```
root@thorin:# cat build_user_sessions_init_script.painless 
state.all_queries = [];
```

There some place in doc to read about install stored scripts from filesystem?.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File-based scripts have now been deprecated, and replaced by [Stored scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts).

The only clue has been... [elastic/elasticsearch#24552](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24552) & [elastic/elasticsearch#24555](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/24555)